# logout should redirect to :back unless :back requires a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

When logout is clicked I want to redirect back to the page the user was on unless that page requires a user to be logged in.

scenario 1 - "back" requires a user
1) User clicks logout from user account page
2) redirected (ultimately) to root_path

scenario 2 - "back" does not require a user
1) User clicks logout from (not user required) events page
2) redirected (ultimately) to events_path

It's been suggested I update my before_filter :require_use method to be something like this:

```
  def require_user
    unless current_user
      flash[:notice] = "You must be logged in to view this page"
      redirect_to user_coming_from_logout_method? root_path : login_path
    end 
  end
```

Except I've been unable to define `#user_coming_from_logout_method?`

One might think that it is simply:

```
request.referrer == "/logout"
```

But in the above example request.referrer actually == "/user_account", not the intermediate logout method.  Very weird, I know.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can rely on the browser to set the referrer on a redirect. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158283/will-a-302-redirect-maintain-the-referer-string) discusses that issue in some detail.

Maybe set something in `session` in the logout controller, which you test for and then clear in the `require_user` method?

Comment: dont think this would work for scenario 2 -- in that case the user never hits the #require_user method and therefore this session thing would never be cleared.  It'd be left dangling and probably result in something unexpected down the line.

Comment: ..unless you also have a `require_no_user` method?

Comment: doesn't that imply that every method must either require_user or require_no_user? that's not the case.  I suppose I could add an after_filter to clear the session thing -- that's epic overkill though.

Comment: Good point... it's not quite as simple a problem as it appears at first glance