# Get HTTP Referrer on Redirection

Tags: php, referrer, http-referer

How can you get the HTTP Referrer when redirected from another website, not when they click on a link since it would work for `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, but it doesn't work when a user has been redirected a website and the referrer would be empty.

What will be the method to get the referrer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can you get the HTTP Referrer when redirected from another website

You can't. If the redirection takes place under your control, you can add the original referer as a parameter, but if the external redirector doesn't do that, you have no way to get hold of the information.

Comment: Aw. So there is absolutely no way to know where the user came from when the user got redirected?

Comment: @YouBook not as far as I know, no.

Comment: Javascript redirects send HTTP Referer header. See here for a more detailed description and use case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71839517/2717254

Answer (score 4):

An example of how I did it. Say we have 3 pages, one calling the next.

```
page1.com -> page2.com -> page3.com.
```

in page2.com get the page1.com using:

```
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];//=page1.com
```

when redirecting to page3, send $referrer as a GET parameter

```
page3.com?referrer=$referrer
```

in page3 read the $referrer from the get.

```
$initialReferrer = $_GET['referrer'];//=page1.com
```

Comment: One could directly call a `page3.com?referrer=page4.com` so take care about security/allowance issues. Plus, `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] must be `rawurlencode`-d before being appended to the URL.