# PHP Redirect Without Losing Refererrer URL

Tags: php, redirect, referrer

Is there a way to redirect or refresh page in PHP which will not lose the referrer?

For Example: Page1.php is being redirected to Page2.php So in this case, there is no referrer at all. I want to get referrer on Page2.php

And

A Visitor must be able to press BACK button in his/her browser to go back to Page1.php

*When I redirect from Page1.php to Page2.php then Google Analytics or other website Analytics solutions should be able to track the Referrer who referred Page2.php

I tried both of the below.

With This:

```
header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' ) ;
```

And This:

```
header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" );
```

I really need a way out for this. Spent 7 hours straight to find the solution. But I'm unable to find.

Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks,

Comment: When the user presses the back button - what should be displayed then?

Comment: Have you tried passing a referer header with your Location? `header('Referer: http://blah.com/');`

Comment: @Yogu When the user presses back button on Page2.php he should be returned to Page1.php

Comment: @jprofitt I tried like you said with header('Referer: http://blah.com/'); 
But it's not working :(

Comment: What guys?? No one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the referrer URL in a session variable before sending the redirect header.

Comment: I couldn't do that and if I do that it's useless for me. Because when I redirect from Page1.php to Page2.php then Google Analytics or other website Analytics solutions should be able to track the Referrer who referred Page2.php

Answer (score 0):

There has been a helpful discussion about 302 Redirects, Apache Configuration and possible work arounds at [Will a 302 redirect maintain the referer string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158283/will-a-302-redirect-maintain-the-referer-stringa)

Comment: Will it help me any way to accomplish this? ----> When I redirect from Page1.php to Page2.php then Google Analytics or other website Analytics solutions should be able to track the Referrer who referred Page2.php

Answer (score -1):

a `302 redirect` response should preserve the referrer *by convention* - although this isn't specified anywhere as far as I know.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. I didn't get you.

When I redirect from Page1.php to Page2.php then Google Analytics or other website Analytics solutions should be able to track the Referrer who referred Page2.php