# Capture HTTP Traffic

Tags: c#, http

Short version:
I am looking to make sure that a URL (partial match) is requested (client-side).

Long Version:
I am looking to automate part of my testing. Currently I use Fiddler2 to manually verify.

Here's the scenario:

1. User navigates to Site A
2. My app redirects using a tracking URL (seen in Fiddler's HTTP traffic)
3. User ends up on Site A, parameters now applied.

I would like to verify, in C#, that step 2 happened by doing a partial match (contains {string} for example).

Question:
How should I go about this? I have started looking into `HttpWebRequest` class and `FiddlerCore`, but my love using the simplest code possible (so other team members to update if needed) lead me to ask what the users of StackOverflow would recommend.

Comment: Have you looked at using something like selenium RC to do this instead via a browser? That could be less work than inspecting the traffic.

Comment: Yes, I use Telerik Test Studio. The problem is that my URL in step 2 is only seen in the browsers address bar for a split second. I am aiming to monitor/sniff the traffic so that I can ensure that URL is hit before ending up on the URL in step 3 of my example. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Follow Up:**
I ended up using Telerik's proxy to send HTTP Requests and parse the responces via C#. Here's the article that was used as a springboard:

https://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/advanced-topics/coded-samples/general/using-the-http-proxy

Comment: your resource is down

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [SharpPcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/). It's based on pcap (WinPcap on Windows), which is the packet capture library that is used by the popular [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

There is a really great tutorial on CodeProject with lots of example code to get you started: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12458/SharpPcap-A-Packet-Capture-Framework-for-NET

Once you have a hold of the packets (SharpPcap does capture, not parsing), you can use [Packet.Net](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/packetnet/index.php?title=Main_Page) to parse the packets into something usable (HTTP communications, in your case).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will look into SharpPcap as I can run the C# code as a test step in my automation suite.

Comment: Unfortunately theres an Installer that has to be run in order to get the C# app working. :/

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Didn't see #2 as an intermediate URL when I read the question, it looked like it was the (only) redirect action. Depending on your [browser of choice, and the type of redirect performed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158283/will-a-302-redirect-maintain-the-referer-string), you can use Selenium to read the page referrer and get the redirect.

```c#
WebDriver driver; // Assigned elsewhere
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

// Call any javascript
var referrer = js.executeScript("document.referrer");
```

---

I would recommend [Selenium Webdriver](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) for all your web site/app testing needs in C#. It integrates very nicely with NUnit, MSTest and other test frameworks - it's very easy to use.

With Selenium Webdriver, you will start an automated browser instance (Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer, PhantomJS and others) from your C# testing code. You will then control the browser with simple commands, like "go to url" or "enter text in input box" or "click button". [See more in the API.](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations)

It doesn't require much from other developers either - they just run the test suite, and assuming they have the browser installed, it will work. I've used it successfully with hundreds of tests across a team of developers who each had different browser preferences (even for the testing, which we each tweaked) and on the team build server.

For this test, I would [go to the url in step 1](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#fetching-a-page), then [wait for a second](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-and-implicit-waits-reference), and read the url in step 3.

Here is some sample code, adapated from [Introducing the Selenium-WebDriver API by Example](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example). Since I don't know the URL nor `{string}` ("cheese" in this example) you are looking for, the sample hasn't changed much.

```c#
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

// Requires reference to WebDriver.Support.dll
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

class RedirectThenReadUrl
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver.

        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.

        // Further note that other drivers (InternetExplorerDriver,
        // ChromeDriver, etc.) will require further configuration 
        // before this example will work. See the wiki pages for the
        // individual drivers at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki
        // for further information.
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        //Notice navigation is slightly different than the Java version
        //This is because 'get' is a keyword in C#
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");

        // Print the original URL
        System.Console.WriteLine("Page url is: " + driver.Url);

        // @kirbycope: In your case, the redirect happens here - you just have
        // to wait for the new page to load before reading the new values

        // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until((d) => { return d.Url.ToLower().Contains("cheese"); });

        // Print the redirected URL
        System.Console.WriteLine("Page url is: " + driver.Url);

        //Close the browser
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, we already use an automated suite called Telerik. The problem is that it's not as easy as going to a URL and waiting a moment. This is because the URL I am looking for is kind of a middle man and your solution (above) would show me the URL in step 3 of my example and not the URL seen in step 2.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to sniff HTTP traffic. You could use a packet capture driver like winpcap, import that DLL and test, or use **SharpPcap** that @SimpleCoder mentioned.

The path of minimum effort would be write a [**FiddlerScript Addon**](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/dev/), to check the request and redirect if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am going to forgo the Fiddler route as calling an external service will cause issues with my automation software as it does not have a "blocking action" to tell the test script to wait for the other process and then continue the next automated steps.