# asp.net tell where request came from in Page_Load

Tags: asp.net

If a request for my page was from a redirect from another site, can I tell which site that was from in the Page_Load function? If so, how secure and accurate is this? Can it be spoofed fairly easily?

Answer (score 1):

[HTTP Referer info isn't guaranteed, it's optional](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2158283/304683) nor is it "accurate". A series of redirects, which is commonly done by ad agencies, will likely only provide you with (if) the original redirect (not the others along the way).

Can it be spoofed easily? **Yes**, just mimic/generate any http request and provide any `Referer` you want in the HTTP header.