# request.environ['HTTP_REFERER'] is None

Tags: python, flask

i want to get `HTTP_REFERER` in python flask framework.
My route is this:

```
@app.route('/login')

def login():

    if authenticateForPanel():
        return redirect(url_for("panel"))
    else:               
        ref = request.environ['HTTP_REFERER']

        return render_template('login.html',blogOptions = g.blogOptions,ref=ref)
```

When i execute this,i got `KeyError: 'HTTP_REFERER'` with the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ozcan/flask/flask/app.py", line 1823, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/ozcan/flask/flask/app.py", line 1811, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Users/ozcan/flask/flask/app.py", line 1809, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/ozcan/flask/flask/app.py", line 1482, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/ozcan/flask/flask/app.py", line 1480, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/ozcan/flask/flask/app.py", line 1466, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/ozcan/Documents/python/app.py", line 318, in login
    ref = request.environ['HTTP_REFERER']
KeyError: 'HTTP_REFERER'
```

When i first wrote this code it was working.I do not directly call this url.I call `localhost:5000/panel` and it redirects me to the `login` method.So basically there should be a referer,am i wrong?

When i print the `request.environ['HTTP_REFERER']` it prints `None`

I also tried with the

`ref = request.referrer` but it is `None`

Why it can be happen?Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

The werkzeug Request wrapper, which flask uses by default, does this work for you: [request.referrer](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.CommonRequestDescriptorsMixin.referrer)

```
from flask import Flask, request
import unittest

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return unicode(request.referrer)

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test(self):
        c = app.test_client()
        resp = c.get('/', headers={'Referer': '/somethingelse'})
        self.assertEqual('/somethingelse', resp.data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But in the more general case, to retrieve the value of a dictionary key specifying a default if the key is not present, use [dict.get](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

Answer (score 4):

> When i first wrote this code it was working.I do not directly call
>   this url.I call localhost:5000/panel and it redirects me to the login
>   method.So basically there should be a referer,am i wrong?

This is not correct. A redirect does not guarantee a referrer. Whether a browser will provide a referrer is browser-specific. Perhaps you were using a different browser that had this behavior at one point? The code you have now is working as best as it can be expected to.

See [Will a 302 redirect maintain the referer string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158283/will-a-302-redirect-maintain-the-referer-string)

Comment: then,how can i set a referer?

Comment: As the answer to the question I linked stated, the most surefire way is to not leave this up to the browsers. Instead, include the URL of the referrer as a parameter in your URL. So, something like `http://example.com/login?referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpanel`.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could get request.referrer to not be None is to load the page through `<a href="/something"></a>`. Redirecting and making regular old HTTP requests did not include a referrer attribute.

Answer (score 0):

@dm03514 has the right idea, but if you're insistent upon using the `environ` dictionary, you should be using the `get` method. Also, how are you testing that it is None, i.e., are you using the interactive interpreter to print the value or are you adding print statements in the body?

An example of how you would do this reasonably:

```
# snip
else:
    ref = request.environ.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    # You can specify a default return value other than None like so:
    # ref = request.environ.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/')
# snip
```

Comment: to check it i print the ref variable to terminal

Comment: sorry but nothing has changed

Comment: You mean you add print statements and run the server. And if you're still getting the above exception, you must not have restarted your server. The `get` method does not raise an exception EVER unless the object has no such method.

Comment: No no i did not meant that.I wrote print ref and run the server.I do not have still above exception but now HTTP_REFERER is None