# python+pyramid getting every time HTTP_REFERER as empty or none

Tags: python, django, curl, pyramid, pylons

In my pyramid view i want to get HTTP_REFERER so first i tried `self.request.environ.get('HTTP_REFERRER')` in first time it was working fine but letter it start giving me `empty/none`.

then i tried all the way like

```
self.request.environ.get('HTTP_REFERRER')

self.request.referrer

self.request.url
```

and all still i am not getting `HTTP_REFERRER` even there is no key in `self.request.environ`

i changed browser setting also inside `about:config` then `network.http.sendRefferHeader` then also i could not solve my problem

and in my case none of the condit

entered the site URL in browser address bar itself.

visited the site by a browser-maintained bookmark.

visited the site as first page in the window/tab.

visited the site programmatically (like, curl) without setting the referrer header (searchbots!).

and all

Please suggest me how to get `HTTP_REFERER`

i am using pyramid and pylons framwork pylons api calling pyramid api.

Comment: Have you take a look at this [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941030/request-environhttp-referer-is-none)

Comment: There will be no HTTP_REFERRER unless the user was redirected to your page.

Answer (score -1):

The browser does not always send referrer header. Please check Wikipedia HTTP Referrer page for more information about the behavior. If the browser doesn't send this header, or it is stripped off by proxy, web server or whatever then the value is not set.

`request.referrer` is the correct way to access this field in Pyramid / WebOb based HTTPRequest objects.