# Http Referer not working PHP

Tags: php, referer

I'm trying to register with an HTML form, here's what i've got so far:

1. I have the form in a file under `http://localhost/hospital/administrador/registrar-usuario/index.php`
2. This is sent to a file where I check, clean, etc the variables introduced, This file is under `http://localhost/hospital/administrador/registrar-usuario/verify.php`
3. What I want is that if the user makes mistake, I create a session with an array of errors in it and the values the user previuosly entered. Then `header('Location: .');` redirect them to the `index.php`. So I can display the erros and save the values of the form, so there's no need to rewrite them all.
4. Here's the problem: at the beggining of the `index.php` I check whether the user came from the `verify.php` page or not. If they don't the session with the values and errors destroys. But the `HTTP_REFERER` says that the referer is `http://localhost/hospital/administrador/registrar-usuario/index.php` instead of `verify.php`

Any ideas of what's going on?

Thanks a lot!!

Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will a 302 redirect maintain the referer string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158283/will-a-302-redirect-maintain-the-referer-string)

Comment: No it won't, it's still giving me the index page as the referer

Comment: Your symptoms seem to be what's said in the answers in that question. The referer is the original page, not the page in the middle that contains the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

As per http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php `HTTP_REFERER` can not be trusted as it can be changed.

Is it safe enough to say if you are on `index.php` and your session variable (whatever you called it) has errors in it, display them, and destroy? Else do nothing?

I am not sure if you are using a framework or which framework but you may be having a weird redirect issue.

Comment: Hi! I'm not using any framework. The weird thing is it works for me if   I test it at (http://localhost/hospital/index.php) and (http://localhost/hospital/verify.php) Even though the HTTP_REFERER is like the index page I still get the desired effect. But not when I'm folder levels up...which I know... makes no sense