# How to find IP address of redirecting server in php

Tags: php, http-status-code-302

I have two `servers A and B`. User accesses some page on `server A` and `server A` sends redirection `(302 status code)` and returns. now client sends the request to `server B`.  So now what I want is some way to find the ip address of the server A from this request, any identity of server A will do the work, `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is coming blank.

**PS: I have control on Server B only not on A.
Also if I access the page of server A directly (which is sending redirect to Server B) I am getting blank referer at server B.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will a 302 redirect maintain the referer string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158283/will-a-302-redirect-maintain-the-referer-string)

Comment: modified the question, please check

Comment: You didn't really modify it. Anyway, as you'll see in the answers to the question above, you can't get the hostname (or IP) of the server issuing a 301/302 redirect. The only information you get is what's in `$_SERVER`, unless you can get the other server to append its hostname to the query string.

Comment: I'm pretty sure @Mike is right. When following a redirect, there's nothing that indicates the page that sent the redirect.

Comment: @Mike It doesn't seem to be a duplicate of that. He's not interested in the original `Referer`, he wants a new parameter that contains the intermediate URL.

Comment: @Barmar You're right. My mistake.

Comment: Thanks guys, however I was pretty surprised why referer wasn't sent?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the IP of the referrer (i.e. the server that initiated the redirect to your server).