# JSP : How to get the URL Address of the page that redirects to another page in java?

Tags: java, jsp, http

I'd like to get an URL address of the page that redirects me to another page, in other words suppose that I have three jsp file with the names of one.jsp, two.jsp and three.jsp. the codes of each of them can be seen in the below section:

one.jsp

```
    <a href="two.jsp">go to page two</a>
```

two.jsp

```
        <%
            response.sendRedirect("three.jsp");
        %>
```

three.jsp

```
        <%
            out.print(request.getHeader("referer"));
        %>
```

the out put of these will be `http://localhost:8080/one.jsp` , but instead I expected to get `http://localhost:8080/two.jsp` as the result.

Now I've got two question:

1. why I get 'one.jsp' as a result?
2. How can i get the URL address of pages that do redirecting? ( in this case `two.jsp`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour depends on the browser and seems not to be defined, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158283/will-a-302-redirect-maintain-the-referer-string/5441932).

Therefore it is simpler to add parameter information about the redirect to the redirect URL and evaluate that parameter in `three.jsp`:

two.jsp:

```
<%response.sendRedirect("three.jsp?source=two");%>
```

Comment: It's a good solution because each time I can evaluate the source parameter, but do you want to say that there is no java feature that can handle this duty without passing any parameter?

Comment: @ElyasHadizadeh its not that Java/servlets have no feature to access the information but rather that the information (e.g. the referer header) sent from browser is not reliable.

Comment: thank you buddy ! one +1 for your answer, but still I don't tick it as an accepted answer maybe there is one person to have another solution, but one more question, you've said `information (e.g. the referer header) sent from browser is not reliable`, may I ask you why? why it is not reliable? I didn't get you.

Comment: its not reliable because it is browser specific and not RFC standard specific. Each browser has the option to implement it as they wish...