# GoogleAnalytics doesn't catch my domain as referrer but browsers does

Tags: php, redirect, google-analytics

I have a service that we can consider it as a redirect url service . so when I open google analytics realtime screen I didn't find my domain in top referrers list .

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: ".$url); 
exit();
```

my configurations is a 301 request status, chrome browser detect my domain as a referrer but google analytics not. redirect is from http to http

Any idea how I can figure out this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay .. I figured it now guys ... you should pass 
`?utm_source=YourWebsiteName&utm_medium=referral`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, use:

```
header("Location: ".$url,TRUE,301);
exit();
```

Comment: unfortunately nothing happened

Comment: You must add this code at the top of your page, before any output

Comment: And the referer can be null after redirect. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158283/will-a-302-redirect-maintain-the-referer-string

Comment: it's on the top of the page , referrer is recorded in browsers request info but google doesn't record it at all this is the problem .. everything works fine except google analytics referrers list.