# How to Detect Last Referrer Domain in PHP?

Tags: php, image, redirect, iframe

Suppose a website `xyz.com` sends a visitor to my web page `domain.com/test.php?id=1` and for security reasons, I've added some PHP sessions in test.php and redirect the visitor to `domain.com/process.php`.

Now I want to redirect the visitor from `process.php` to a website say `example.com`.

The problem here is `xyz.com` can send visitors from `iframe` or `img` tag as below:

`<img src="http://domain.com/test.php?id=1" height="0" width="0" alt=""/>`

which will also be counted as a valid visitor as all the codes will run in `test.php` as well as `process.php` but the visitor will not be redirected to `example.com`

To prevent this I thought to check if the visitor is referred to `process.php` from `test.php` of `domain.com` or from `xyz.com`.

Code I use to check the referrer domain in `process.php`:

```
<?php
$ref = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST);
if($ref != "domain.com"){
echo "Bad Referral";
exit;
}
else {
header("Location: http://example.com");
}
?>
```

Now the problem here is, the above code gives referrer domain to `xyz.com` only.
How can I get the latest referrer domain?

The target here is to redirect the visitor successfully to `example.com` and not be cheated from fake redirects from `img` or `iframe` tags. Any other method will also be appreciated. Only PHP codes required. No JavaScript.

Comment: Both route are through test.php -> process.php, so it is not important whether the browsers take the latest URL as referer or not. (BTW they don't do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158283/will-a-302-redirect-maintain-the-referer-string )
I suggest to make difference between the two routes with a parameter. For example: http://domain.com/test.php?redirect=0

Comment: Both pages have parameters.